# When Isotop/masonry 1st loaded it get crumpled all together how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope, masonry

When Isotop/masonry 1st loaded it get crumpled all together how to fix ? but after i refresh it it just got back to normal. Visit [this link](http://nov11.asia/) to check it live.

[image: 1st load]

[image: after refresh]

Answer (score 0):

Unloaded images can throw off Isotope layouts and cause item elements to overlap. imagesLoaded resolves this issue. [Here are the instructions](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html#imagesloaded) on how to utilize it. Isotope v2 does not include it so you need to  download and load it in your page.

Comment: I have used Isotope PACKAGED v2.2.0 , but it mess up like above screenshot

Comment: If you read the answer, you will see that v2 of isotope does not include imagesloaded.js. You need to load it separately

Answer (score -1):

If your layout has images, you probably need to use [imagesLoaded](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded).

Overlaping items are caused by items that change size after a layout. This is caused by unloaded media: images, [web fonts](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html#web-fonts), embedded buttons. To fix it, you need to initialize or [layout](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#layout) after all the items have their proper size.

You can use ImageLoaded by adding some JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://imagesloaded.desandro.com"></script>/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js

// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    // options...
});
// layout Isotope after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $grid.isotope('layout');
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, @om, didn't I say that in my answer?